# addEventListener to children js - pure js

Tags: javascript

I want to use pure Javascript to set `addEventListener` to children of a parent, i.e. changing an image `src` by clicking on child element(one of the dots and change img source). but only by using index of children.

```
    <div class="carousel-slide">
    <img src="img/1.jpg" id="img1" alt="" />    
    </div>
    <div class="dots" id="dots">
        <span class="dot" id="dot1"></span>
        <span class="dot" id="dot2"></span>
        <span class="dot" id="dot3"></span>
        <span class="dot" id="dot4"></span>
        <span class="dot" id="dot5"></span>
        <span class="dot" id="dot6"></span>
    </div>
```

I know a few ways to change `src` but I have no idea for shortest and better Javascript code.

Is it possible to set `addEventListener` to all children and use them?

Comment: For performance reasons, it's generally better to create an event listener on a root component (such as your div with id="dots". Then in your event listener function, you could use e.target to get the properties of the actual element that was clicked within that container. The one event listener could cover all your dots.

Comment: im noob, can u show me by codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab the index after adding the eventListener to the parent.

```
var dots = document.querySelector(".dots");

dots.addEventListener("click",function(e){
  var index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(dots.children, e.target);
  console.log(index)
});
```

Comment: tnx, and how can find out what number the child is?

Comment: @MPERSIA I have updated my answer to what you are looking for

Comment: tnx sir, your answer is the best

Answer (score 1):

For performance reasons, it's generally better to create an event listener on a root component (such as your div with id="dots". Then in your event listener function, you could use e.target to get the properties of the actual element that was clicked within that container. The one event listener could cover all your dots. Here is an example of how you may accomplish this.

```
<div class="carousel-slide">
    <img src="img/1.jpg" id="img1" alt="" />    
</div>

<div class="dots" id="dots">
    <span data-src="http://" class="dot" id="dot1"></span>
    <span data-src="http://" class="dot" id="dot2"></span>
    <span data-src="http://" class="dot" id="dot3"></span>
    <span data-src="http://" class="dot" id="dot4"></span>
    <span data-src="http://" class="dot" id="dot5"></span>
    <span data-src="http://" class="dot" id="dot6"></span>
</div>
```

```
var dotsContainer = document.getElementById('dots');
var imageContainer = document.getElementById('img1');

dotsContainer.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    imageContainer.src = e.target.dataset.src;
});
```

Using Data Attributes

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Event Target (e.target)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target

> e.target refers to the clicked <li> element
> This is different than e.currentTarget which would refer to the parent <ul> in this context

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach, you take the parent element and you add an event listener to it and then you can access the child element using `e.target`

```js
var dots=document.getElementById("dots")
var img = document.querySelector("#img1");

dots.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
   if(e.target==e.currentTarget) return
   dot= e.target
   img.src = dot.getAttribute("set-src");
   console.log(img)
})
```

```html
<div class="carousel-slide">
    <img src="img/1.jpg" id="img1" alt="" />    
    </div>
    <div class="dots" id="dots">
        <span set-src="http://1" id="dot1">1</span>
        <span set-src="http://2" id="dot2">2</span>
        <span set-src="http://3" id="dot3">3</span>
        <span set-src="http://9" id="dot4">4</span>
        <span set-src="http://4" id="dot5">5</span>
        <span set-src="http://5" id="dot6">6</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: this will thrown an exception - you have to define dots as var dots

Answer (score 1):

Here only the `<div>` containing the dots, and the `<img>` that needs to be changed were selected in JS.
When a dot is clicked, that dot is returned as `event.target`
Name it "dot" `dot = event.target`
You get the image attribute of that dot: `event.target.getAttribute("data-img")`
You set the `<img>` source to the "dot" img attribute:
`img.src = dot.getAttribute("data-img");`

```js
var dots = document.querySelector ("[data-js='dots']");
var img = document.querySelector (".carousel-slide img");

dots.addEventListener ("click", function (e){
  var target_img = e.target.getAttribute ("data-img");
  img.src = target_img;
  console.log (img.src);
});
```

```html
<div class="carousel-slide">
    <img src="initial-img" id="img1" alt="" />    
    </div>
    <div class="dots" data-js="dots">
        <span class="dot" data-img="img1">dot1</span>
        <span class="dot" data-img="img2">dot2</span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello this is how you can do this: https://jsfiddle.net/vmospu3f/35/

```
<div class="carousel-slide">
        <img src="img/1.jpg" id="img1" alt="" />    
        </div>
        <div class="dots" id="dots">
            <span class="dot" id="dot1" data-img-src="img/2.jpg"></span>
            <span class="dot" id="dot2" data-img-src="img/3.jpg"></span>
            <span class="dot" id="dot3"></span>
            <span class="dot" id="dot4"></span>
            <span class="dot" id="dot5"></span>
            <span class="dot" id="dot6"></span>
        </div>   
    
     var dots = document.querySelectorAll('.dot'),
                imgElement = document.getElementById('img1');
        
        dots.forEach(function(dot) {
          dot.addEventListener('click', function() {
            imgElement.src = this.getAttribute('data-img-src');
          });
        });
```